# How do I show an alert box without top level window?

Tags: actionscript-3, air

Adobe AIR provides Alert.show().  However this seems to fail if there is no top level window like in the typical tray example ("Example: Creating an application with no windows"):

http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/taskbar_1.html

I failed to make Alert.show() work in this situation.  Seems that there is no alert() either.

Is there any way to show an alert prompt (modal or nonmodal) in such a situation without reinventing the wheel?

Example AIR tray application skeleton:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:WindowedApplication xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
        xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
        xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
                       windowComplete="init(event)" visible="false">
 <fx:Script>
  <![CDATA[
   import flash.events.InvokeEvent;

   import mx.controls.Alert;
   import mx.events.CloseEvent;

   import mx.events.AIREvent;

   // As windows does not work without icon, we MUST embed it.
   // Stories told differently on the net are void.
   [Embed(source="icons/AIRApp_16.png")]  private var img16:Class;
   [Embed(source="icons/AIRApp_32.png")]  private var img32:Class;
   [Embed(source="icons/AIRApp_48.png")]  private var img48:Class;
   [Embed(source="icons/AIRApp_128.png")] private var img128:Class;

   private function helloworld(evt:Event):void {
    //This does not work
    Alert.show("hello world");
   }

   private function closer(e:CloseEvent):void
   {
    if (e.detail == Alert.YES) {
     NativeApplication.nativeApplication.icon.bitmaps = [];
     NativeApplication.nativeApplication.exit();
    }
   }

   private function doexit(event:Event):void {
    //This does not work either
    Alert.show("Really?","Exit application", Alert.YES | Alert.NO | Alert.NONMODAL, null, closer, null, 3);
   }

   protected function init(event:AIREvent):void {

    NativeApplication.nativeApplication.autoExit = false;

    var iconMenu:NativeMenu = new NativeMenu();

    var exitCommand:NativeMenuItem = iconMenu.addItem(new NativeMenuItem("Exit"));
    exitCommand.addEventListener(Event.SELECT, doexit);

    NativeApplication.nativeApplication.icon.bitmaps = [new img16, new img32, new img48, new img128];

    if (NativeApplication.supportsSystemTrayIcon) {

     var systray:SystemTrayIcon = NativeApplication.nativeApplication.icon as SystemTrayIcon;
     systray.tooltip = "Monitor Application";
     systray.menu = iconMenu;
     systray.addEventListener(ScreenMouseEvent.CLICK, helloworld);

    } else if (NativeApplication.supportsDockIcon) {

     var dock:DockIcon = NativeApplication.nativeApplication.icon as DockIcon;
     dock.menu = iconMenu;
     NativeApplication.nativeApplication.addEventListener(InvokeEvent.INVOKE, helloworld);
    }
   }

  ]]>
 </fx:Script>
 <fx:Declarations>
  <!-- Platzieren Sie nichtvisuelle Elemente (z. B. Dienste, Wertobjekte) hier -->
 </fx:Declarations>
</s:WindowedApplication>
```

Note the "visible=false" which must be preserved even that this is what's causing the trouble.

Comment: BTW the icons can be found in the AIR SDK sample folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.  Application, in both Air and Flex, is your root level object.  All alerts have to be children of that object.  If a parent has visible=false, then no child will be seen.

Sorry.

Have you considered possibly setting visibility to true right before calling Alert.show()?

Comment: Thanks, I feared exactly that.  The window shall be hidden while the Alert is shown.  So I think I only have two choices:
A) To re-invent the wheel, so create a myAlert window class or
B) switch the main window to transparent and chromeless, such that it virtually does not show up and use Alert.show()
Well, I go for variant A) then, sigh.  Thanks.